# Getting a loading seam to work with 2x2 metatiles

Tags: assembly, graphics, 8080, game-boy

I'm working on a prototype for a scrolling loading seam similar to Pokemon where the screen scrolls incrementally by 8 pixels with each direction button press, and new tile graphics are drawn off the visible screen. To compress the data I'll be using 2x2 "metatiles" and a vertical column of metatiles will be drawn which goes down the entire height of video memory. I've tested these routines and gotten them to work the way I want, so my current goal is to get the loading seam to work. I've run into one major problem - the right half of the previously drawn metatiles gets overwritten by the newly drawn metatiles.

Before scrolling:
[image: This is my test screen before any scrolling]

After scrolling right twice (the first column drawn is the same color as the background that was already there and thus can't be seen):
[image: after scrolling right once]

After scrolling right three times:
[image: this is where the error happens]

I've circled a number in the third picture. This is the variable `LOADSEAM_PTR_X` which keeps track of which column of VRAM to draw the new column of metatiles into. My code ensures that it's 0x16 larger than `scroll_x >> 5` at all times, but gets `AND`ed with 0x1F so that it "wraps around," so to speak. But I need to get the loading seam to also increment by 2 while staying out of the visible screen. I'm at a loss for how to do that, I've tried adding an additional 1 to the loading seam pointer every other time the screen scrolls, but that proved ineffective.

The code responsible for all this is a bit long, but here it is:

```
;this runs in the main game loop
    LD A,(SOFTSCROLL_X)
    and %11111000
    rrca
    rrca
    rrca                ;divide by 8, gets scroll value reduced to nearest column
    LD (TILEX),A        ;RANGES FROM 0 TO 1F
    add &16             ;visible screen is &14 tiles wide, so be 2 beyond that to stay off camera
    and &1F             ;CONSTRICT RANGE
    LD (LOADSEAM_PTR_X),A

;below this, the input handler is called, and when the right key is pressed this is what happens:
     push af
     push hl
        rst &30    ;calls a wait for screen refresh so the scroll can be modified.
        ld hl,SOFTSCROLL_X   ;current horiz. scroll value
        ld a,&08             ;this is how much to scroll the screen
        add (hl)          
        ld (hl),a            ;scroll right 8 pixels
        gb_out <scx          ;macro for LDH, writes to whatever memory location scx is.
        call doLoadingSeam_RightScroll   
        ;this is what draws the column, it's not relevant to the question.
    pop hl
    pop af
    ;continue button checks after this
```

Comment: Somehow this sounds not very RC.SE specific, but a generic programming issue, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe? I guess you've got a point, I'm not having problems with the hardware itself so I'll ask on stackOverflow. Is there a way to relocate this question to StackOverflow or a different stackExchange?